Ubuntu 22.04 freezing issues on Dell Latitude 7390
Short version
I'm experiencing frequent system freezes on my Dell Latitude 7390 running Ubuntu 22.04. The freezes occur during video playback in Firefox and shortly after rebooting, even at the login screen. Here's what I've tried so far without success:

Using an older kernel version
Running a memory test with pcmemtest (no errors found)

I also wrote a script to monitor the system's temperature, memory, and disk health, but the logs show normal readings before freezing. The system is about 6 years old, so it's out of warranty. Any suggestions on further tests or potential fixes?

Long version
I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell Latitude 7390. The system freezes completely after using it for a while.
When watching a YouTube video in Firefox, the video freezes and the audio loops the last second repeatedly. However, this issue is not limited to video playback. After rebooting by pressing the power button, the system often freezes again shortly, sometimes even at the login screen.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Using an older kernel version, which did not help.
Running a memory test with pcmemtest, which found no errors.

To diagnose the problem, I wrote a script to monitor the system:
LOG_FILE=~/system_monitor.log
MAX_SIZE=10485760  # 10 MB in bytes

while true; do
    # Check log file size and truncate if necessary
    if [ -f "$LOG_FILE" ]; then
        LOG_SIZE=$(stat -c%s "$LOG_FILE")
        if [ "$LOG_SIZE" -gt "$MAX_SIZE" ]; then
            echo "Log file exceeded $MAX_SIZE bytes, truncating." > "$LOG_FILE"
        fi
    fi

    # Append system information to the log
    echo "=== $(date) ===" >> "$LOG_FILE"
    sensors >> "$LOG_FILE"
    smartctl -a /dev/sdX >> "$LOG_FILE"  # Replace /dev/sdX with your drive identifier
    free -h >> "$LOG_FILE"
    df -h >> "$LOG_FILE"
    echo "" >> "$LOG_FILE"
    
    sleep 60
done

The last entries of the log before the freezing are as shown below in the picture. As you can see, at least 1 minute before the freezing, everything—memory, CPU temperature, hard drive, swap memory—all seem to be fine.
=== Wed 24 Jul 2024 07:30:18 PM CST ===
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +44.0°C  

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:002-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          20.00 V  (min =  +5.00 V, max = +20.00 V)
curr1:         3.25 A  (max =  +3.25 A)

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:001-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           5.00 V  (min =  +5.00 V, max =  +5.00 V)
curr1:         0.00 A  (max =  +0.00 A)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:           8.34 V  
curr1:       1000.00 uA 

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +49.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +49.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

dell_smm-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Processor Fan:    0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 8900 RPM)
CPU:            +49.0°C  
Ambient:        +43.0°C  
Other:          +40.0°C  
SODIMM:         +38.0°C  

pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +44.0°C  

nvme-pci-6d00
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +47.9°C  (low  = -20.1°C, high = +84.8°C)
                       (crit = +81.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +47.9°C  (low  = -20.1°C, high = +84.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.5.0-44-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       THNSF5512GPUK NVMe SED TOSHIBA 512GB
Serial Number:                      471S107ZTFET
Firmware Version:                   5KDA5103
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x1179
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x00080d
Controller ID:                      0
NVMe Version:                       <1.2
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          512,110,190,592 [512 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            00080d 0200223257
Local Time is:                      Wed Jul 24 19:30:18 2024 CST
Firmware Updates (0x02):            1 Slot
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x001e):     Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat
Log Page Attributes (0x02):         Cmd_Eff_Lg
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     78 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     82 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     6.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     2.40W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     1.90W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0120W       -        -    3  3  3  3     5000   25000
 4 -   0.0060W       -        -    4  4  4  4   100000   70000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         2
 1 -    4096       0         1

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        48 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          50%
Percentage Used:                    13%
Data Units Read:                    34,991,513 [17.9 TB]
Data Units Written:                 39,561,681 [20.2 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 827,292,395
Host Write Commands:                586,929,076
Controller Busy Time:               5,299
Power Cycles:                       4,838
Power On Hours:                     19,026
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   374
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               48 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 128 entries)
No Errors Logged

               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15Gi       2.8Gi       9.1Gi       299Mi       3.7Gi        12Gi
Swap:           15Gi          0B        15Gi
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                          1.6G  3.1M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p4                 220G  138G   71G  67% /
tmpfs                          7.8G  684K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
efivarfs                       384K   61K  319K  16% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme0n1p2                 231G  141G   79G  65% /media/user/data
/dev/nvme0n1p1                 197M   36M  162M  18% /boot/efi
tmpfs                          1.6G  1.7M  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
appimaged-715-x86_64.AppImage  5.0M  5.0M     0 100% /tmp/.mount_appimaNeMnkI
pCloud.fs                      500G  161G  340G  33% /home/user/pCloudDrive

(BTW, I noticed that a large number NUL (ASCII code 0) inserted at the end of the log file.)
I am completely lost here. The laptop is about 6 years old, so the warranty has expired. If it's a memory or hard drive failure, I can replace them, but I'm unsure what other tests I can run to diagnose the issue.
Update
I just tried to run Ubuntu via a bootable USB key. It froze at the screen where I choose between "Install Ubuntu" or "Try Ubuntu".
Update 1
After updating to Ubuntu 24.04, the frequency of freezing seems to have reduced. I let it playing YouTube video over night and it was still running in the morning. Yet it still occurs at random time. For example, the last time it freezes, I was just trying to editing this post a minute ago.
I have also visited a Dell computer repair shop. The technician there tested my hard drive and believe it is OK. When I suggested to replace the motherboard, he told me it does not worth the money since this is an old computer.
Fortunately I have another laptop which I can use so I will be using that one from now on.

I would suggest giving Ubuntu 24.04 a try and maybe even write a separate USB drive and/or try the one you're currently using in another computer, just to rule things out.  You can also try to install memtest on a separate USB drive and let it run through its tests at least once.

@Ray Good idea! I have just bought a new USB. I will try run 24.04 on it.

Have you tried stress testing your GPU?

@amar My laptop has Core 7 (8th Gen) CPU with an integrated graphic card. Should I still test it? Any suggestion on how to do it? Thanks.

That may help  https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-gpu-monitoring-and-diagnostic-commands/

Also this https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/12/gpu-usage-ubuntu-22-04/

Did you mean that the USB that you used was new?  If so, it is possible that is the cause.  i.e., just because it is new doesn't mean that it works.  It could be a manufacturer's defect.  Try to rule that out as well, even if it is unlikely (i.e., seems like your computer froze and not that it had problems reading the drive).

@Ray I have tried two USB keys to run live Ubuntu, both of them freeze a short time after using.

Ah!  It seems it's not a problem with the USB keys, then.  See if 24.04 works.  But also test the memory chips using memtest86+.  See here.

@Ray tested the memory for 8 passes. No problem. The hard drive is also OK.

Do you have any device connected to the computer?

Maybe it is time to give 24.04 a try.  And yes, as @amar says, is there anything connected to it when you boot?

Yes. I am trying 24.04 with completely fresh install. It has frozen twice so far. It might be connected to USB some how. One of the time when it froze, I was clicked on the icon on the side bar to open an external hard drive. I will keep the USB ports free for now and see if that helps.

If this still does not work, I will install a windows just to see if there is any problem or more diagnosis information.

Do you have Intel graphics? When I boot the 6.8.x kernel, the Intel Arrandale GPU on my Latitude e6410 are completely unstable. See here. Adding intel_iommu=off as a boot parameter worked for me.

@TSJNachos117 Yes. I do have intel CUP with integrated Graphic Card. It has been stable lately. I am not sure if it's because of kernel. But I will check it.

reply if works. I fixed mine by turning off the power management of wifi.
first, try to find the power management is on or off.
iwconfig

if Power Management: on
open your network manager power management option by
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

you'll find
wifi.powersave = 3
change this 3 to 2.
now reboot your PC
then check again
iwconfig

Power Management:off
this should solve the problem.

Thanks. I will give it a try.

This does not seem to help, unfortunately.

Sorry to hear. I don't think I found any other solution to redirect you. Keep searching.

I don't see why this setting could effect it at all. It's a Firefox problem - looks like memory release issues.

NOTICE: This will only work on intel processors
I found a fix and described it here:
Xubuntu 22.04 freezes randomly during use
This problem appears to be solved in my particular situation now by altering the boot menu in terminal
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
Alter line with default to this by adding intel_idle.max_cstate=1 to parameters (inside the quote marks)
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
Press Ctrl+O to save changes. Enter. Ctrl+X to exit
sudo update-grub
restart computer
I also increased the swap to 8Gb, double the RAM

Please put the full details in, not just a link - thanks!

Ok Will. However the full details ARE in the link... No point creating duplicates
